# Could not install package 'BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET 2.4.633'...project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5'

Tags: libtiff.net

Trying to upgrade BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET via NuGet from v2.4.633 to v2.4.626

Error: Could not install package 'BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET 2.4.633'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

626 has dependencies set to NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.1)
633 is set to NETStandard.Library (>= 2.0.0)

Is .Net Framework 3.5 supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest package that supports .NET 2.0 and .NET Standard 1.3 is [2.4.626](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BitMiracle.LibTiff.NET/2.4.626)

Newer packages only support .NET 4.0 and newer, and .NET Standard 2.0 and newer

Answer (score 1):

.NET Standard requires Framework 4.5 as a minimum. .NET Standard 2.0, which libtiff.net uses, requires 4.6.1 or better.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Looking at their github, it seems they are trying to multi target Framework 2.0, Framework 4.0, netstandard1.3, and netstandard2.0. That should let you use it via the Framework 2.0 components, but in my experience those multi target packages often don’t work quite right. You could try opening a bug report with them and see if there’s something that could be tweaked in the package to make older frameworks behave.